# Authentication Fail When Trying to Add Package to My Project via HTTPS with Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

In my Xcode settings, I'm logged into my GitHub account (where 2fa is turned on) as a Source Control Account. I currently have it set up to use SSH and my SSH key. I've created an access token and securely saved that string on my machine. I can successfully add the package when I use an SSH URL (which makes sense, such as `git@github.com:{username}/{repo_name}.git`.

I can't get adding via HTTPS to work for some reason. It always results in the following error:

`Error while fetching remote repository: https://github.com/{username}/{repo_name}.git`

`Authentication failed because no credentials were provided.`

Is this a known Xcode error? I haven't found an answer here on SO. Is it because I'm using 2FA? All the packages have the same instruction which is essentially "Just copy and paste this URL into SPM to add" but that's never worked for me.

Would love some insight here. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to create a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Comment: I did that. I mentioned in that in the 3rd sentence of my post. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to add your own private packages or public packages?  For the former, did you change your github login in Xcode to use https with your username and the PAT?  Xcode only uses what is in its own preferences

Comment: Public packages. When I added my GH account in Xcode, I signed in with my username and password and selected HTTPS but I get the error above

Comment: I just removed my GH account. Clicked add, entered my email and personal access token, then added an example package URL like `https://github.com/AppPear/SwiftUI-PullToRefresh`. I'm asked again for my access token which I give it and then it fails over HTTPS. I've set the Clone Using method as HTTPS and have provided my ssh key, just in case. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure what is going on there.  You don't even need a GitHub account set up in Xcode to add packages from public repositories

Comment: @ZackShapiro were you able to solve this problem, if so, how? I am getting the same errors with GitHub https links

Comment: @JippeJoosten I haven't tried this since updating to Xcode 12 but what I was doing in Xcode 11 was just using the SSH url

Comment: You can also change from https to http in the url, for a quick fix

Answer (score 14):

We solved this by removing a problematic setting in `$HOME/.gitconfig`:

Deleting:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Comment: This was the issue. It seems xcode tries to fetch swift packages with HTTPS. So this breaks it.

Comment: Hi @Paul Beusterien , I have updated the global git config url with below command:
```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```
And verified it by below command:
```
git config --global --edit 
```

Also I have updated my projects git config with url (instead of command)
But I am still facing this issue. I am doing it or is there something else I should do?

Comment: I didn't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not sure why this was happening (sometimes crashing!) in my project, but I noticed it worked fine in other Xcode projects. So, I sunk a couple days into re-creating the project file from scratch (new project, same name, re-add files, re-add packages, re-set settings, etc.).

That fixed it and now I can add and remove packages all I want